# How change the style of inserted text - javascript

Tags: javascript, fonts, textbox

i have created a script that interacts with html page. In html page the user insert in a textbox an expression. There are 5 checkbox in the page, this checkbox sets the font style (big, fixed, strike, bold etc...). Depending on the selected checkboxes, must show a new windows with the edit text corresponding at the value of the selected checkboxes. I would  in other two select box (dimension and colour) of the text. This is my html code, can show me an example?

```
<input type="text" id="testo"><br>
<label>big</label><input type="checkbox" id="big"><br>
<label>italics</label><input type="checkbox" id="italics"><br>
<label>bold</label><input type="checkbox" id="bold"><br>
<label>fixed</label><input type="checkbox" id="fixed"><br>
<label>strike</label><input type="checkbox" id="strike"><br>
<label>sub</label><input type="checkbox" id="sub"><br>
<label>Colore</label><select id="colore">
<option value="1">Blue</option>
<option value="2">Green</option>
</select><br>
<label>Dimensione</label><select>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="button" value="mostra testo" onclick="Show()">
```

Comment: Difficult to understand what you're asking here.

Comment: i would change the text style..

Answer (score 0):

Using `jQuery` you can do it in the following way:

```
function Show() {
  $('testo').css('background-color', function(){
             return $('colore').value()
            })
}
```

For more details check out [.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/). I did not test my code, but it should be something like this.